# SiriKit - cannot load view from UI Extension

Tags: ios, sirikit

I am trying to show the view from my storyboard when starting a workout in my app. But apparently I am doing something wrong because the view gets never loaded. I have put the INStartWorkoutIntent in the plists of both extensions but the `func configure(with interaction: INInteraction!, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: ((CGSize) -> Void)!)` method never gets called. Should I make some specific call so that the view shows? The `resolve` and `handle` method in the other extension get called.

Comment: The same thing works with messages intents btw.

Comment: the same problem here... Finally someone asked for this also...

Comment: I asked the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41046532/2725435

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load custom UI for INStartWorkoutIntent as You can provide an Intents UI extension if you are supporting intents in the following domains:
Messaging,
Payments,
Ride booking,
Workouts.

take a look https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ProvidingaCustomInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH7-SW1

Comment: INStartWorkoutIntent is in the domain Workouts, but as it seems it doesn't support Intent UI Extension or it's some bug or something

Comment: hey, is it a bug or not?