# SiriKit, How to display response for start Workout Intent?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

**IntentHandler** class:

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, INStartWorkoutIntentHandling {

    public func handle(startWorkout intent: INStartWorkoutIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartWorkoutIntentResponse) -> Void) {

        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INStartWorkoutIntent.self))
        let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: userActivity)
        completion(response)
    }

    //MARK: - INStartWorkoutIntentHandling

    func confirm(startWorkout intent: INStartWorkoutIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartWorkoutIntentResponse) -> Void) {

        completion(INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: nil))
    }
}
```

Apple documentation says:

[image]

Siri opens the app, but I need to display UI from IntentUI. How to do this?

In other words: **How to prepare to display response, load intents UI extension, prepare interface and display it in code?**

[image]

**IntentViewController** class:

```
import IntentsUI

class IntentViewController: UIViewController, INUIHostedViewControlling {

    //MARK: - INUIHostedViewControlling

    func configure(with interaction: INInteraction!, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: ((CGSize) -> Void)!) {

        if let completion = completion {
            completion(self.desiredSize)
        }
    }

    var desiredSize: CGSize {
        return self.extensionContext!.hostedViewMaximumAllowedSize
    }
}
```

Base on [this](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/adding-siri-to-ios-10-apps-in-swift-tutorial/) tutorial it is possible indeed.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have MainInterface value for NSExtensionMainStoryboard in your Info.plist?

Comment: yes, it is nested within `NSExtension` key and it is included for my `IntentTimerUI` extension, not for `IntentTimer`.

Comment: How about `IntentsSupported` key?

Comment: yes, it is nested in `NSExtensionAttributes` for both: `IntentTimer` and `IntentTimerUI`.

Comment: Try to change it to `INStartWorkoutIntent` only

Comment: I have only one item inside `IntentsSupported` array: `INStartWorkoutIntent`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130674/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-niko-adrianus-yuwono).

Answer (score 1):

Although Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ProvidingaCustomInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH7-SW1):

> You can provide an Intents UI extension if you are supporting intents in the following domains:
>   Messaging
>   Payments
>   Ride booking
>   Workouts

I think it is quite impossible, because response responsible for open UI is not prepared for this:

Please look at `INSendMessageIntentResponseCode` for `INSentMessageIntentHandling`:

```
public enum INSendMessageIntentResponseCode : Int {


    case unspecified

    case ready

    case inProgress

    case success

    case failure

    case failureRequiringAppLaunch

    case failureMessageServiceNotAvailable
}
```

and `INStartWorkoutIntentResponse` for `INStartWorkoutIntentHandling`:

```
public enum INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode : Int {


    case unspecified

    case ready

    case continueInApp

    case failure

    case failureRequiringAppLaunch

    case failureOngoingWorkout

    case failureNoMatchingWorkout
}
```

For the second one, there is only `.continueInApp`, and this is exactly what happens here, opposite to the first one where exists: `.success` and `.inProgress`

Comment: I am facing same issue, do you mean that  it is impossible to add IntentUI for Workout Domain ?